# Why not "ich werde sehen dich"?

Tags: word-order

I used [Reverso Context](https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/ich+werde+sehen+dich) to search for any instances of "ich werde sehen dich" but every example is using a slightly different form where "sehen" and "dich" are **displaced**.

Why is **"ich werde dich sehen"** okay and **"ich werde sehen dich"** not?
What's the general rule for word placement? **Shouldn't the verb (sehen) be the second element of the sentence?**

Comment: Can you explain from any research you've taken (at your grammar book or the online resources), why you believe that _**"ich werde sehen dich"**_ would be correct?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I assumed that verb should be the second element of the sentence. https://www.thoughtco.com/german-sentences-in-the-right-order-4068769

Comment: @VahidAmiri and it actually is - "werde" is a verb.

Comment: @Eller That's what confused me. I didn't think it was a verb.

Comment: @VahidAmiri the answer is literally in the NEXT sentence. "With compound verbs, the second part of the verb goes last, but the conjugated part is still second."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

German word order requires all non-finite verbs to appear in final position. In subordinate clauses, the finite verb occurs in this position as well. In main clauses, the finite verb and the finite verb only is fronted.

> because I **must<sub>1</sub> have<sub>2</sub> seen<sub>3</sub>** this before
>   weil ich das schon einmal **gesehen<sub>3</sub> haben<sub>2</sub> muß<sub>1</sub>** *(subordinate clause, finite verb in final position)*
>   denn ich **muß<sub>1</sub>** das schon einmal **gesehen<sub>3</sub> haben<sub>2</sub>** *(main clause, finite verb in second position)*

Wikipedia has an article on [German sentence structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_sentence_structure).